# Behaviour of the Cartan Maurer form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-algebras, differential-forms

Let there be a Lie-group $G$ and its Lie-algebra $g$. Then the Cartan Maurer form is an 1-form $\omega: T_gG \rightarrow T_eG$ for which holds:

$$ (L^\ast_g)\omega = \omega$$

In Shlomo Sternberg's book "Curvature in Mathematics and Physics" it is said on p. 155:

$$d\omega (X,Y) = X\omega(Y) - Y\omega(X)- \omega([X,Y])$$

But as $X\omega(Y)=0$ and $Y\omega(Y)=0$ the first two terms will disappear.

Why is this valid ? It is even said in the last sentence of the corresponding section of Sternberg's book p.155 that for left-invariant vector fields $\omega(Y) = Y$ and $\omega(X) =X$. The explanation provided by Sternberg is that resulting element of the Lie-algebra is constant, but apparently this element varies if the vector field $X$ plugged into $\omega$ varies.

I could even conclude:

$$X\omega(Y) - Y\omega(X) = XY -YX =[X,Y]\neq 0$$.

Why is this wrong ? I am a physicist and I only have very basic knowledge on differential geometry, so I would appreciate an answer which can be easily understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One should distinguish between a vector $X\in T_eG$ and the associated left-invariant vector field $\underline{X}$ on $G$. With this notation, the Maurer-Cartan form is the $T_eG$-valued differential form on $G$ defined by $\omega(\underline X)=X$ for any $X\in T_eG$. So $\omega(\underline X)$ is not a vector field, it is a function on $G$, valued in the vector space $T_eG$. As its value doesn't depend on the point $g\in G$, the derivative of this function is $0$.